# Does baby powder cause ovarian cancer?

Tags: cancer

There has been an article circulating on social media which says that a 1982 study implicates baby powder usage in ovarian cancer.

> As early as 1982, studies have shown a link between baby powder and ovarian cancer in women. Findings have shown that women using talc­based powders are 300 times more likely to be diagnosed with cancer.

- [Source: Talcum powder allegedly causing cancer](http://www.healthyfoodstar.com/this-powder-is-causing-cancer-in-10000-women/)

Is there any truth to this claim?

Comment: Earlier in the article it seems to say "33%" not "300 times" (not that I'm complaining about this question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 2008, there was a critical review of the evidence that using talcum powder in the perineal region might cause ovarian cancer.

Here is the paper:

- Muscat JE, Huncharek MS, [Perineal talc use and ovarian cancer: a critical review.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18287871) Eur J Cancer Prev. 2008 Apr;17(2):139-46. doi: 10.1097/CEJ.0b013e32811080ef.

The full-text of a draft submission for the paper is available [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3621109/).

It found that,

- several studies had found an association. *(Keep reading, there is a twist!)*
- the relative risk was about 1.3 - which means 30% more likely, not 300 times more likely.
- although talc has a similar classification to asbestos, it is not carcinogenic like asbestos.
- the studies had a number of holes (e.g. inconsistent dose-response effects), raising concerns about their validity as evidence of causation.
- there are inconsistencies between these findings and other studies of the safety of talc.

They conclude that these findings are NOT enough to conclude that talcum powder causes ovarian cancer:

> Talc is not genotoxic. Mechanistic, pathology and animal model studies have not found evidence for a carcinogenic effect. In summary, these data collectively **do not indicate that cosmetic talc causes ovarian cancer**.

Comment: Does the term "cosmetic talc" have an exact meaning, or is it just common parlance to mean "pure"? And then, pragmatically, if a product just says "talc" in thr ingredients, can that include lots of other things?

Comment: @fredsbend: I am not an authority on what they meant, but I assume it was to distinguish the baby powder mixture from mineral talc in its natural form.